# If $A$ is Noetherian ring with ideal $I$, then $I$-adic completion ${\hat{A}}$ is Noetherian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, cauchy-sequences, noetherian, artinian

This is proposition 10.26 in Atiyah Macdonald
I was trying to prove it. **In the proof they are using $ \hat{A}$ is complete implies $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=0}\hat{I^n}=(0) $**

I am not getting how to prove this,
I took $x \neq 0\in \bigcap^{\infty}_{n=0}\hat{I^n}$ and tried to construct cauchy sequence $(x+\hat{I^n})_n$ but I am not getting any contradiction.

can I get  some hint to prove $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=0}\hat{I^n}=(0) $

Comment: you mean that the completion is noetherian as well?

Comment: @MatyMangoo yes

Comment: You should edit then your statement. It is in general true that $\hat{I} \subset \mathrm{rad}(\hat{R})$. Now you can use Krull's Intersection Theorem. Does it help you?

Comment: @MatyMangoo   Thanks for replying, in order to use   Krull's Intersection Theorem we need $\hat{R}$ to be finitely generated, but it is not given.